# Problems with socket.io via cluster in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

Socket.io is doing multiple requests to perform handshake and establish connection with a client. With a cluster those requests may arrive to different workers, which will break handshake protocol.
I try to use radis, but with no success

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var config = require('./config/environment');

if(cluster.isMaster) {

  var server = require('http').createServer();
  var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
    serveClient: (config.env === 'production') ? false : true,
    path: '/socket.io-client',
    pingInterval: 25000,
    pingTimeout: 30000
  });
  var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

  socketio.adapter(redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }));

  var numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;

  for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  } 
} else {
  startServer();
}
// Start server
function startServer() {
  var express = require('express');
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var multer = require('multer');

// Connect to database
  mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

// Setup server
  var app = express();

  app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));

  var server = require('http').createServer(app);
  var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
    serveClient: (config.env === 'production') ? false : true,
    path: '/socket.io-client',
    pingInterval: 25000,
    pingTimeout: 30000
  });
  var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

  socketio.adapter(redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }));

  require('./config/socketio')(socketio);
  require('./config/express')(app);
  require('./routes')(app);

  server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
  });

  // Expose app
  exports = module.exports = app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right in the socket.io doc for [using multiple node servers with socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/), it says this:

> If you plan to distribute the load of connections among different
>   processes or machines, you have to make sure that requests associated
>   with a particular session id connect to the process that originated
>   them.

It then goes on to explain how that can be done with a nginx proxy.

Or, if using multiple clustered processes all on the same machine, there's a [sticky-session module](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) that can be used with the node.js clustering.  Looking at the code, the sticky-session module does a hash of the IP address and uses that hash to always assign it to the same clustered server instance.